# How to consume HttpContext in old ASP.NET web forms application and new ASP.NET core application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard, httpcontext

I'm converting all of our shared class libraries from .NET Framework to .NET Standard so that they're consumable by both our older .NET Framework and our new .NET Core applications. The goal is to get all of our applications to .NET Core, but it's a large system so will take time so we need the two worlds to coexist for a year or so in the meantime.

One of the pain points is that the shared class library code leverages HttpContext extensively. I understand that the new .NET Core way to access it from within class libraries is to use [AddHttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2). However, we still have old ASP.NET web forms applications AND new ASP.NET Core web applications that both need to call this common code. If I switch to using HttpContextAccessor with DI then it won't work from the old ASP.NET Web Forms app, as it has no concept of what HttpContextAccessor is.

I'm wondering what my options are here... Is there a way to set up access of HttpContext such that it can be consumable both in ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET Core?

Comment: What things are you accessing off the HttpContext?

Comment: @davidfowl Here is everything we're using: https://gist.github.com/justintoth/44b4afe4a7f065ed5675d133f8b829f4

Comment: I'm in the same boat, and the answer I frequently see from the .NET team and other devs is "just rewrite your whole app from scratch lol", it is a bit grating.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have some common interface between both the old and new applications I would think.

Create a new IMyHttpContext and inject that type into both the old and the new. Use your DI infrastructure to instantiate a new `MyClassForOld: IMyHttpContext` that accesses an underlying reference `HttpContext` for the old apps and use your DI to instantiate another new `MyClassForNew: IMyHttpContent` that accesses an underlying reference to HttpContextAccessor

Comment: I don't see how that would work in practice... We leverage a lot of http context / request / response code (https://gist.github.com/justintoth/44b4afe4a7f065ed5675d133f8b829f4) so I don't see how an interface would allow access to all of these classes / methods / properties.